# JWT in .net core - do 'ValidIssuer' and 'ValidAudience' in TokenValidationParameters need to match the generated token?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I'm attempting to setup and understand JWT in my .net core 2.1 application but one part has me confused.

I have the following setup in my `startup.cs`

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:JwtIssuer"];
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "John",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "Dave",
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                (Configuration["Authentication:JwtKey"])),
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
```

I've purposely put weird values for `ValidIssuer` and `ValidAudience`.

My token generation then looks like the following...

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Authentication:JwtKey"]));          
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);          
var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["Authentication:JwtExpireDays"]));

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: _configuration["Authentication:JwtIssuer"],
    audience: _configuration["Authentication:JwtAudience"], 
    claims: claims, 
    expires: expires, 
    signingCredentials: creds);

return new TokenViewModel
{
    AccessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
    AccessTokenExpiration = expires,
    FirstName = user.FirstName,
    LastName = user.LastName
};
```

Here I am setting `issuer` and `audience` to the corresponding values in the `appsettings.json` file.

I thought that the `ValidIssuer` and `ValidAudience` from my `startup.cs` would need to match the `issuer` and `audience` in my generated token, however this doesn't seem to be the case. Calls to an endpoint with `[Authorize]` work as expected if a token if provided.

Why does it still work? Shouldn't it be checking the correct issuer and audience details?

**EDIT**

Example token generated by my token endpoint...

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdHVAcmF0Y2xpZmZlLmlvIiwianRpIjoiZWQyNmU0MjgtNjA3Yy00ZjZlLTg3ZjUtNjM1ZTU3MWQzNzQyIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZWlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiIxIiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZSI6InN0dUByYXRjbGlmZmUuaW8iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTU1OTgzNDU2NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIn0.CES0g8UCC8LArDkd8Q4s4a6mhXbkZVGiy3-hJ2Z0IqI`

Decoded has the following payload...

```
{
  "sub": "stu@ratcliffe.io",
  "jti": "ed26e428-607c-4f6e-87f5-635e571d3742",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "1",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "stu@ratcliffe.io",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "exp": 1559834566,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

No issues using this token to query an authorized endpoint even though my issuer and audience of **http://localhost:5000** in the token does not match my issuer of **John** and audience of **Dave** in my **startup.cs**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the token you generated with wired issuer and audience ?

Comment: @TaoZhu I've added an example token, also decoded as an edit. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication();` in your `Startup.Configure()` ?

Comment: @TaoZhu I do. It's right before `app.UseMvc(...)`

Comment: I just create a new webapi project and run your code, but I don't have any cookies in PostMan's response view, so what is the cookies in your screenshot ?